# EF: Should I include foreign key ID's in my entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I know with EF conventions they're not explicitly required, but in real world development I find it really useful to be able to simply update an entities foreign key, rather than attach the relevant related entity. My feeling is that it's better to have both options available so that either could be used in it's given use-context, but it just feels a like I'm polluting my POCO's with properties that are more a database construct than an OO construct.

Would appreciate thoughts from the Pro's out there.

**Without foreign keys**

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public int ProductGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual System_ProductGroup System_ProductGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubGroup> ProductSubGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSection ProductSection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GeneralTranslation> GeneralDescriptionTranslations { get; set; }
}
```

**With foreign keys**

```
public class ProductGroup
{
    public int ProductGroupID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Foreign Keys
    public int System_ProductGroupID { get; set; }
    public int ProductSectionID { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual System_ProductGroup System_ProductGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductSubGroup> ProductSubGroups { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSection ProductSection { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GeneralTranslation> GeneralDescriptionTranslations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It depends on your model... It's usually good if you're willing to avoid lazy loading, or if the parent (or childs) are big enough to really harm the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is better to avoid including the foreign keys in some situations, provided that you already have the `virtual` entity that the keys refer to as a property, and that you are not lazy loading. If you have these properties already, then the foreign key is just a redundant piece of data that could be grabbed from the `virtual` entity itself.

At the end of the day, the foreign keys are meant to link you to other entities, and, as you said, they are more of a database construct. As the developer, you know what column the foreign key links to in the `virtual` entity, and you can access that property accordingly, so excluding the foreign keys from your POCO entity will not eliminate your access to that data.

To @HiperiX's point (in his comment), eliminating the foreign key, itself, will consequently eliminate your ability to lazy load. If you are going to be doing certain logic with the keys that would determine whether or not to grab the referenced entity, then including the foreign keys would be a good idea. I have updated the wording of my post to reflect this caveat.

Comment: Not sure I understand how eliminating the inclusion of a direct foreign key would hamper my ability to lazy load... wouldn't lazy loading still be available by use of the virtual keyword and lazy loading enabled on the context?

Comment: I may have explained it poorly, but what I was trying to get at is the fact that the only way you will be able to get the value of the foreign key would be to get the entity that it refers to and then get the property of that entity that corresponds with the key. As such, if you are looking to filter a set of `virtual` entities down to those with certain values for a column that your foreign key refers to, you would have to get all of the `virtual` entities BEFORE getting the value you are filtering against. Thus you would not be lazy loading that `virtual` entity.

Comment: Ah, I got you now, thanks.

Comment: Anytime - good luck and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually I try to avoid. The notion of foreign key relates to relational DB, that is to the persistence level. And even with POCO dedicated to be used as DAO I prefer removing unecessary reminders to an underlying technology.

But there is on case when I found them usefull: when you want that SomeCollection.Remove(x) delete also in the database.

In this case, with EF, you have to build, for the collectioned entity, a composite PK including a FK. So in this case you need the FK in your POCO.

Answer (score 1):

I think in most cases it comes down to personal preference. I include them because I am responsible not only for the development of the application, but also development of SSRS reports. Including the foreign keys lets me control the names of the foreign key fields and helps ensure that when it comes time to write queries, I know how the tables are joined.